# How do i fix the white space format for my twoString method?

Tags: java, string, formatting

For my homework, we have to create a list that looks like this.

Employee List:

```
Amy       Williams  6345.00
Ese       Nguyen    4231.16
Jacqui    Smith     1988.20
Srilatha  Patel      525.00
```

However my whitespace is off by one extra space for the first three names and i don't know how to fix it

I'm getting this instead:

Employee List:

```
Amy       Williams   6345.00
Ese       Nguyen     4231.16
Jacqui    Smith      1988.20
Srilatha  Patel      525.00
```

So when i try

```
public String toString() {
    String statement = String.format("%-9s %-10s %.2f%n",  this.firstName, this.lastName, this.monthlySalary);
    return statement;
   }
```

I get the extra space on all but the last person on the list. I'm not sure how to format my twoString method to include only the needed amount of white space

Comment: try replace `%.2f` with `%-7.2f`

Comment: That fixed my error! Can you explain why i should've made this change?

Comment: You should tell `format` your desired width of the number; otherwise, it won't know how to keep them aligned

Comment: @lidaobing Do you not mean `%7.2f` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are correct, I did not verify with code

Comment: Two strings? I only see one though...